# Android: Values priority

Tags: android, device

In my app in the `res` folder, there are values folders for different devices. For example:

> values-mdpi
>   Values-hdpi
>   values-v14
>   values-v17
>   values-w480
>   values-w720

etc.

I wonder what is the priority of these folders for Android?

Let's imagine couple devices:

```
first : 480*800  hdpi v14  
second: 320*480  mdpi v17  
third : 720*1280 hdpi v17
```

What folder would Android use for each of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the priority of resource folders [here in this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes). Basically it is used to support different devices and configurations.

Android uses a certain logic to determine the best possible matching resource folder for a device. This is explained in [this documentation page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Regarding your devices query:

- First: 480 * 800 hdpi v14 -- values-hdpi
- Second: 320 * 480 mdpi v17 -- values-mdpi
- Third: 720 * 1280 hdpi v17 -- values-w480

In the list provided by you, `values-w480 (devices with lowest width of 480dp, only from API 13)` has got the highest merit. So whichever device meets that criteria, it'll take resources from that folder.

The `values-vXX (devices with API >= XX)` has got the lowest merit. So if the other folders are not taken, then only Android takes resources from this folder. [Check the table](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2) listing the resources qualifiers for more info on that topic. The resource qualifiers are listed in the table in the order of precedence of resource qualifiers.

- First case: Normal hdpi - less than 480dp width -- So values-hdpi
- Second case: Normal mdpi - less than 480dp width -- values-mdpi
  (values-mdpi has got more weightage than values-v17)
- Third case: hdpi device with width of 480dp (720/1.5 = 480) API 17 --
  values-w480

Comment: Also it's very important to keep in mind when U use smallest width/height qualifiers that for example sw600dp doesn't mean "smallest width 600px" but "smallest width 600*<screen dpi> pixels".
I didn't get it at first :)
Might be useful for newbies as I am

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Android documentation states:

> Be aware that, when the Android system picks which resources to use at
>   runtime, it uses certain logic to determing the "best matching"
>   resources. That is, the qualifiers you use don't have to exactly match
>   the current screen configuration in all cases in order for the system
>   to use them. Specifically, when selecting resources based on the size
>   qualifiers, the system will use resources designed for a screen
>   smaller than the current screen if there are no resources that better
>   match (for example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen
>   resources if necessary). However, if the only available resources are
>   larger than the current screen, the system will not use them and your
>   application will crash if no other resources match the device
>   configuration (for example, if all layout resources are tagged with
>   the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a normal-size screen). For
>   more information about how the system selects resources, read How
>   Android Finds the Best-matching Resource.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

[How Android Finds the Best-Matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)